# PHP - Return array from function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, post

I am submitting a form, using the following function `(prize.php)`:

```
loadmodule('validate'); //This just loads the validate.php function.
    $validate = new Validate;
if($_POST)
    {
        $validateForm = $validate->validateForm();


        switch($validateForm)
        {

                case 1:
                    $error = 'You\'re not logged in..';
                    $stop = true;
                break;

                //If no error = success.    
                if($validateForm['code'] == "100"){
                    $won = $val['prize'];
                    $type = $val['type'];
                    $success = 'You have won! The prize was '.$won.' '.$type.'';
                    die($success);
                }


        }
            die($error);
    }
```

This is the function to validate the form `(validate.php)`:

```
function validate()
                {


                    global $userdata;

                    if(!is_array($userdata))
                        return 1; // User not logged in - return error code one.

                    //If no error, lets show a success message.
                    $prize = "100";
                $text = "dollars";
                    return array("code"=>"100","prize"=>"$prize","type"=>"$text");

                    }//If won



                }
```

The above code returns:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: error in /home/.../public_html/pages/prize.php on line 27
```

Although, it shouldn't throw an error there, since the `die($success)` should be triggered by the code 100.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its easy to spot. If the case is not 1, you will get that notice because then `$error` is not defined.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Can you provide an example? Im lost right now..

Comment: Are `$validate->validateForm()` and the `validate()` function you show supposed to be the same? In that case, that's one of the problems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$error = '';
$stop = false;
switch($validateForm){
            case 1:
                $error = 'You\'re not logged in..';
                $stop = true;
            break;
}


            //If no error = success.    
            if($validateForm['code'] == "100"){
                $won = $val['prize'];
                $type = $val['type'];
                $success = 'You have won! The prize was '.$won.' '.$type.'';
                die($success);
            }
```

first guess is that the `if($validateForm['code'] == "100"){` is ment to be outside the switch.

```
$validateForm = $validate->validateForm();
```

returns an array.. later on your're doing a `if ($validateForm==1)` in the switch.. when $validateForm is an array.

you might have better luck with a simple `is_array()` if statement than the whole switch